# In Vue, can I update a data attribute passed to a method so it then updates the UI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the below code, I expect all 3 buttons to update the associated attributes in the Vue data object, but only the last one updates. Is it possible to update data in the way used for the first 2 buttons?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    anothercounter: 5
  },
  methods: {
    addone: function(c) {
      c = c + 1;
    },
    addonetocounter: function() {
      this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    counter is {{ counter }} : <button @click="addone(counter)">+1</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    anothercounter is {{ anothercounter }} : <button @click="addone(anothercounter)">+1</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    counter is {{ counter }} : <button @click="addonetocounter">+1</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use computed property names. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    anothercounter: 5
  },
  methods: {
    addone: function(c) {
      this[c] = this[c] + 1;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    counter is {{ counter }} : <button @click="addone('counter')">+1</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    anothercounter is {{ anothercounter }} : <button @click="addone('anothercounter')">+1</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. I was getting confused between passing by reference and passing by value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions. Thanks!